# Multiple values of a secure encrypted environment variable in .travis.yml

Tags: encryption, environment-variables, travis-ci

In .travis.yml, is it possible to have multiple values of a secure encrypted environment variable for different builds in the matrix? I want to have a matrix like

```
- VAR1="true" SECURE_VAR=[secure 1]
- VAR2="true" SECURE_VAR=[secure 2]
```

It seems like you can either make the secure variables global to all builds by putting it in `global`, or set them as the only variable for a build by putting `secure` under `matrix`. But I don't even see a way to mix a secure and non-secure environment variable to define a build. Is this possible?

I tried

```
env:
  matrix:
    - VAR1: "true"
      secure: "kJUVmbb8L26E4UNTp3n...="
    - ...
```

In other words, putting them both as keys in a dictionary, which apparently works for normal environment variables. But this caused Travis to error.